# Человеческий перевод "Technology Partners" и "Solution Partners"

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

Дословный перевод "Технологические партнеры" и "Партнеры по решениям" меня не устраивает.
Первое кажется двусмысленным, у меня ассоциация с "технологический университет".
Второе просто не по русски.

Помогите пожалуйста подобрать правильные слова!

Comment: `Technology partner` - ответственный за технологии. `Parner` - компаньон, может быть фирма/сторона и тд. А нельзя ли увидеть кусок контекста? Пару предложений (точный смысл, если что, можно немного размыть/изменить).

Comment: @Sinatr Скорее всего имеются в виду фирмы, которые разработали технологию, которую использует другая фирма (Visa* Technology Partner) или фирмы, совместно с которыми разрабатываются "решения" (Siemens* Solution Partner). Это такие официально-рекламные названия.

Comment: Все верно. Технологические партнеры - их технологии мы используем. Партнеры по решениям помогают конечным пользователям использовать наши продукты. В контексте перефразировать всегда можно. Но мне нужно это в качестве заголовков для страниц сайта.

Answer (score 6):

In 90% of cases *partners* are in fact *providers*. So why not

```
Поставщики технологий
Поставщики решений
```

?

Comment: В контексте "Поставщики" не подойдет. Но спасибо за идею, буду пробовать ее применить с другим словом

Answer (score 1):

These phrases are typical of American business speak. Such speech is designed to be vague, uninformative, and euphemistic while inspiring confidence in the client. "Technology" can mean pretty much anything. "Partner" can describe pretty much any relationship between two participants except that between master and servant.

American business and advertising speak encourages a level of vagueness which is extremely awkward in Russian. I would suggest it is your job as translator to determine the intended meaning from context and express it. For example:

"агенты по распространению наших товаров"

"фирмы сотрудничающие с нами чтобы представлять Вам эту технологию"

"фирмы оказывающие услуги на основании нашей технологии"

"фирмы вступившие с нами в договор об обмене технологами"

Comment: "фирмы одобренные установить" - это что угодно, только не русский :) (К тому же причастные обороты выделяются запятыми.)  Английский язык с ошибками (euphamisticm, speach), что вызывает сомнение в информированности автора.  Посему -1.

Answer (score 0):

Я за первый вариант. Есть же "информационный партнер" (media partner). Оба термина являются заимствованиями из английского языка. В этом смысле изначально заимствованное слово "партнер" будет для русскоговорящих некоторым маркером, обохначающем характер заимствования всего выражения. 
Совет выше заменить "партнеров" на "поставщиков" также хорош. Можно посмотреть в сторону "участников".

Comment: Overuse of foreign modes of expression tends to cloud the message, often so much so that the text becomes a cure for insomnia. The only reason to leave such markers would be if the impression which the client wishes to convey is "we are in touch with foreign culture".

Answer (score -1):

Также можно попробовать такие варианты:

- техническое подспорье
- техническое сопровождение
- техническая поддержка

но изначальные предложения придется перестраивать.

Comment: "Техническое подспорье" - это как-то слишком. Как будто результат работы программы-переводчика.